# How does Distinct() work on a List<> of anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

How does Distinct() work on a List<> of anonymous type? will it just do a property compare? or will it always return the same list?

example:

```
 List<SomeObject> list;
 ....
 ....

 var result = list
           .Where(i => i.Condition)
           .Select(i => new 
               {
                  Name = i.Name,
                  Date = i.Date
               });
           .Distinct()
           .ToList()
```

Please note I applied the distinct on the anonymous-type list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashcode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.

Comment: To emphasize: they have to be the same type. new { X = 1, Y =2 } != new { Y = 2, X =1 } because they're different types. Some code example might clarify your quote.

Comment: @Onots, "they have to be the same type" - absolutely, as the quote says: "two instances of the **same** anonymous type ..."